# Randomizer App as Decision Maker

Tags: java, beginner, android

I am a newbie and self taught in programming.
This is my first attempt to make app.
Appreciate any input or comment to make my code writting skill better.

https://github.com/snufflesrea/Decision-maker

A simple randomize app to give random result from the user's option input. A simple randomize app to give random result from the user's option input. The app has two mode : YES-NO mode and Multichoice mode. The YES-NO mode will show random result between YES or NO option. The Multichoice mode will ask the input from user, and show random result from the input

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

         //set toolbar to the UI
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         if (toolbar != null) {
             toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         }

         // to set the status bar color (on Android Lolipop and above) as per app theme
         Window window = getWindow();
         window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
         window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
         window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

         //Initiate activity if the user click YesNoActivity button
         final Button YesNoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YesNoButton);
         YesNoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, YesNoActivity.class));
             }
         });

         //Initiate activity if the user click Multichoice button
         final Button MultichoiceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MultichoiceButton);
         MultichoiceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, MultichoiceActivity.class));
             }
         });
     }


     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
         // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
         // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
         int id = item.getItemId();

         //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
         if (id == R.id.exit) {

             return true;
         }
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
     } }



 public class YesNoActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private static final Random random = new Random();
     private static final String[] YesNoString = {"YES","NO"};

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.yes_no);

         //set toolbar to the UI
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         if (toolbar != null) {
             toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         }

         // to set the status bar color (on Android Lolipop and above) as per app theme
         Window window = getWindow();
         window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
         window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
         window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

         //In the event the user first click
         final Button YesNoDecision = (Button) findViewById(R.id.YesNoDecision);
         YesNoDecision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 YesNoDecision.setText(randomYesNo());
             }
         });
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle item selection
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.homepage:
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 return true;
             case R.id.exit:
                 super.finish();
                 return true;
             default:
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     }

     //This method to call random YES/NO decision after the button is clicked
     private String randomYesNo() {
         // Select a random Yes/No.
         String decision = YesNoString[random.nextInt(2)];
     return decision;
     }

 }



 public class MultichoiceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     private static final Random random = new Random();
     private static final ArrayList <String> mArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
     private ArrayAdapter mAdapterMultichoice;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_multichoice);

         //set toolbar to the UI
         Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
         if (toolbar != null) {
             toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
         }

         // to set the status bar color (on Android Lolipop and above) as per app theme
         Window window = getWindow();
         window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
         window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
         window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

         //In the event the user click Multichoice Button
         final Button MultichoiceDecision = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MultichoiceDecision);
         MultichoiceDecision.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 MultichoiceDecision.setText(randomYesNo());
             }
         });

         //In the event the user click AddChoice Button
         final Button AddChoice = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AddButton);
         AddChoice.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(MultichoiceActivity.this);
                 LayoutInflater inflater = MultichoiceActivity.this.getLayoutInflater();
                 final View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
                 alertDialog.setView(dialogView);
                 alertDialog.setTitle("ADD NEW CHOICE");
                 alertDialog.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                         EditText dob=(EditText)dialogView.findViewById(R.id.dialogText);
                         String  str=dob.getText().toString();
                         mArrayList.add(str);
                         mAdapterMultichoice.notifyDataSetChanged();
                     }
                 });
                 alertDialog.setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                     @Override
                     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                     }
                 });
                 AlertDialog dialog = alertDialog.create();
                 dialog.show();
             }
         });

         //In the event the user first Clear Button
         final Button ClearAll = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ClearButton);
         ClearAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
             if (mAdapterMultichoice != null)
             { mArrayList.clear();
                 mAdapterMultichoice.notifyDataSetChanged();
             }
             }
         });

         //Show multichoice item on the listView
         mAdapterMultichoice = new ArrayAdapter(
                 getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_listview, R.id.item_listview,mArrayList);
         ListView mListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.MultichoiceList);
         mListView.setAdapter(mAdapterMultichoice);
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
         return true;
     }

     @Override
     public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
         // Handle item selection
         switch (item.getItemId()) {
             case R.id.homepage:
                 Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                 startActivity(intent);
                 return true;
             case R.id.exit:

                 return true;
             default:
                 return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
         }
     }

     //This method to call random item inside MultichoiceDecision after the button is clicked
     private String randomYesNo() {
         // Select a random choice option.
         String decision = "Please add your choice";
         if (mArrayList.size()>0){
         String [] MultichoiceArray = new String[mArrayList.size()];
         MultichoiceArray = mArrayList.toArray(MultichoiceArray);
         decision = MultichoiceArray[random.nextInt(2)];}
             return decision;
     }
 }
```